# Definition of random variable

Tags: probability, random-variables

In some books, they don't define the random variable based on measure theory. Instead, they define as follow (in the book All of Statistics of Larry Wasserman):

[image]

My question is does this definition satisfy the more general definition based on measure theory? In particular, is $X$ a measurable mapping?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it does satisfy the measure theory. For example, the total probability is 1, which also apply to the $X$. You can compare the property of $X$ with the definition of measure theory.

Comment: @sleevechen "the total probability is 1, which also apply to the X" Sorry but what are you talking about?

Comment: I mean for example if head is $X = 0$, tail is $X = 1$. $P(X=0) + P(X = 1) = 1$

Comment: @sleevechen And can this help the OP? Note that defining random variables requires no measure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This definition (probably meant for students not yet familiar with measure theory) is not complete. It should say that a random variable is a *measurable* function mapping from a probability space $\Omega$ to $\mathbb R$.

This means that $(\Omega, \sigma, P)$ is a measurable space with a $\sigma$-algebra $\sigma$ and a measure $P$ of $1$ for which $P(\Omega) = 1$.